# caffe circular shift of zero-padded upscaled images for interpolation

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I want to implement the super-resolution algorithm defined in https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05158 using caffe. There are TF implementations but no caffe implementation yet: https://github.com/tetrachrome/subpixel

To summarize the algorithm: I want to superresolve an image by 3. I want to do the upsampling at the end of the network rather than at the beginning. To do that I will have 9 images (Batch x 9 x height x width) at the end of the network.

Then what I wish to do is to pick one pixel from each image at the same coordinates and place them within 3x3 square to complete an image of size 3*height * 3*width. Similar to:
[image: sub-pixel upsampling]

1) Can I use deconvolution layer to upscale an image by 3, filling zeros in between and if so, how?

2) I am thinking of using slice layer to extract 9 images.

3) Is there a way to circularly shift some images to align them as seen in the image and if so, how?

4) Do I really need slice layer before circular shifting and eltwise summing OR can I do it in another way without needing slice layer: Can I circular shift channels separately and can I merge channels of images by summation?

5) Can this be done in a much easier way which I am unable to imagine.

I asked quite a lot questions I hope I am not overflowing the questions.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

I want to implement this Tensorflow code in caffe:

```
def _phase_shift(I, r):
    bsize, a, b, c = I.get_shape().as_list()
    bsize = tf.shape(I)[0] # Handling Dimension(None) type for undefined batch dim
    X = tf.reshape(I, (bsize, a, b, r, r))
    X = tf.transpose(X, (0, 1, 2, 4, 3))  # bsize, a, b, 1, 1
    X = tf.split(1, a, X)  # a, [bsize, b, r, r]
    X = tf.concat(2, [tf.squeeze(x, axis=1) for x in X])  # bsize, b, a*r, r
    X = tf.split(1, b, X)  # b, [bsize, a*r, r]
    X = tf.concat(2, [tf.squeeze(x, axis=1) for x in X])  # bsize, a*r, b*r
return tf.reshape(X, (bsize, a*r, b*r, 1))
```